# Calculate ISO 8601 time format to hours/minutes from now with Python

Tags: python, datetime, time

How would I receive an input of a string (time in ISO 8601 format) and convert/calculate the duration from then until now?

Input: `2018-09-29T00:33:33Z`

Output: `3 days ago`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil.parser

a = datetime.now()
#a = datetime.strftime(a, format="%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S")
#a = a[:10] + 'T' + a[10:] + 'Z'
a = datetime.strftime(a, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")

a = dateutil.parser.parse(a) - dateutil.parser.parse("2018-09-29T00:33:33Z")
print(str(a))

3 days, 2:00:00
```

Comment: Why the string concatenation, when you use a format string before? Shouldn't `a = datetime.strftime(a, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")` work?

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution using [Arrow](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

```
>>> import arrow
>>> d = arrow.get("2018-09-29T00:33:33Z")
>>> d.humanize()
'3 days ago'
```